# DevExpress. Контрол NavBarControl. Форматирование при наведении указателем мыши

Tags: winforms, devexpress

В Appearances ItemHotTracked задаю форматирование. В результате,  при наведении мыши цвет текста изменяется, но фон остается неизменным. Что нужно сделать, чтобы добиться нужного результата? Спасибо.
[image: Формтаирование]

[image: При наведении указателя цвет шрифта изменился, но фон нет]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo;
using DevExpress.XtraNavBar;
using DevExpress.Utils.Drawing;

namespace NavBarSample {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void navBarControl1_CustomDrawLink(object sender, DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.CustomDrawNavBarElementEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ObjectInfo.State == ObjectState.Hot || e.ObjectInfo.State == ObjectState.Pressed) {
            LinearGradientBrush brush;
            NavLinkInfoArgs linkInfo = e.ObjectInfo as NavLinkInfoArgs;
            if (e.ObjectInfo.State == ObjectState.Hot) {
                brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.RealBounds, Color.Orange, Color.PeachPuff,
                    LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            }
            else
                brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.RealBounds, Color.PeachPuff, Color.Orange,
                    LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.OrangeRed, e.RealBounds);
            Rectangle rect = e.RealBounds;
            rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            if (e.Image != null) {
                Rectangle imageRect = linkInfo.ImageRectangle;
                imageRect.X += (imageRect.Width - e.Image.Width) / 2;
                imageRect.Y += (imageRect.Height - e.Image.Height) / 2;
                imageRect.Size = e.Image.Size;
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(e.Image, imageRect);
            }
            e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.Caption, linkInfo.RealCaptionRectangle, Brushes.White);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}